# Crontab on raspberry pi not running

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a python file on my Raspberry pi and I'm trying to have it run daily. I've checked the script by runing it directly, which works perfectly. But when I set it up in crontab, it's not running on scheduled time. Can someone help me understand what's going wrong?

Here's what I put in crontab

`27 09 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myfile.py`

I feel it might be related the python version? At the beginning of my python script I have this line `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: remove `/usr/bin/python3` and it should work properly.

Comment: What command did you use to *"run it directly"*?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just opened my script and clicked run.

Answer (score 0):

The shebang-Line (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) is only used when called by a shell to determine the interpreter to use.

If your script works with

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myfile.py
```

in your shell, it should work in the Crontab File.

If it does not it is a possibility that the python script is not compatible with Python3 and you need to use Python 2. You may test your script with either

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myfile.py
```

or simply

```
/home/pi/myfile.py
```

If either of these commands will run the script without problem use this command in your contab.

Comment: Thanks for providing a hint. I tested running my script in terminal, both ```/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myfile.py``` and ```/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myfile.py``` didn't work. But ```/usr/bin/env python /home/pi/myfile.py``` worked. Though I'm not sure why is it.